# Php mysqli and stored-procedure

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have a stored procedure:

```
Create procedure news(in dt datetime,in title varchar(10),in desc varchar(200))

Begin
Insert into news values (dt,title,desc);
End
```

Now my php:

```
$db = new mysqli("","","","");

$dt = $_POST['date'];
$ttl = $_POST['title'];
$desc = $_POST['descrip'];
$sql = $db->query("CALL news('$dt','$ttl','$desc')");
if($sql)
{
echo "data sent";

}else{
echo "data not sent";

}
```

I'm new with php please help thank you

My php doesn't work i keep getting the "data not sent" message. Am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

First thing that comes to mind, might not be the only issue:

```
$db = new mysqli("","","","");
```

should be something like

```
$db = new mysqli("localhost","username","pa$$w0rd","database_name");
```

or if you have [your ini set up correctly (see `ini_get()` default values)](http://php.net/mysqli_connect),

```
$db = new mysqli();
```

**Edit**: By the way, you probably really want to use parametrised queries (or just generally escape your input) through-out, your 'CALL' query writes user input directly into the query, you're quite vulnerable to SQL injection. Just imagine what'd happen if someone put in `Description'); DELETE FROM news WHERE (title LIKE '%` into `$_POST['descrip']`:

```
$sql = $db->query("CALL news('...','...','Description'); DELETE FROM news WHERE (title LIKE '%')");
```

Not so good.

Comment: I'm assuming he simply deleted his credentials, as you shouldn't post your DB user/pass on SO.

Comment: @Pachonk: While I don't remember precisely what I thought three years ago, I'm used to people putting placeholders into their constructors like I did. :) (...and far too used to people genuinely making mistakes like that, honestly.) Obviously definitely agreed that one should not share true credentials on stackoverflow - that would be a dire mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think where you have

```
$sql = $db->query("CALL news('$dt','$ttl','$desc')");
```

you need

```
$sql = $db->query("CALL news('".$dt."','".$ttl."','".$desc."')");
```

The first fails because you are sending a string '$dt' as the date-time (and '$tt1' and '$desc' as the field values, for that matter).

Comment: Those two statements are equivalent, though - the query string is in double quotes, so the variables will be substituted in just fine...

Comment: You're quite correct, John, now I try it again. For some reason, when I did it the first time round, it made a difference. Finger trouble somewhere, I expect.